# Не могу завершить дочерний процесс NODE.JS

Tags: node.js, процесс

Есть сервер node.js, при запуске которого должны запуститься несколько дочерних процессов на node.js

```
config.botScripts.forEach(async script => {
    console.log(`${script.options} ${__dirname}${config.relativePath}${script.name}`)

    const task = await childProcess.spawn('start', [`${script.options} ${__dirname}${config.relativePath}${script.name}`], {shell: true})
    
    console.log(task.pid)
    // ls.stdout.on("data", data => console.log(`stdout ${script.name}: ${data}`))
    // ls.stderr.on("data", data => console.log(`stderr ${script.name}: ${data}`))
    task.on('error', (error) => console.log(`error ${script.name}: ${error.message}`))
    task.on("close", code => console.log(`child process ${script.name} exited with code ${code}`))
    tasks.push(task)
})
```

Ну и они естественно запустились. А когда сервер тухнет их соответственно нужно убить, и тут я застрял. Последняя моя попытка:

```
process.stdin.resume()
const exitHandler = signal => {
    console.log(tasks[0].pid)
    tasks.forEach(task => childProcess.spawn('taskkill', [`/PID`,`${task.pid}`, '/f', `/T`]))
    process.exit()
}
// process.on('exit', signal => exitHandler(signal))
process.on('SIGINT', signal => exitHandler(signal))
// process.on('uncaughtException', signal => exitHandler(signal))
```

Также пытался `task.kill(1)` но никак. Заметка - если запускать notepad.exe то оно отработает как надо.

Comment: А зачем тут async/await? `childprocess.spawn` синхронная функция.

Comment: Сигнал `1` это `SIGHUP`, возможно у ваших процессов стоит обработчик этого сигнала, поэтому они не выходят. Попробуйте `task.kill('SIGTERM')` или `task.kill('SIGKILL')`

Comment: Обработчиков нету. Сигналы пробовал разные. Походу PID который у меня на руках не соответствует тому что запущен.

Comment: Хм, так может `start ....` форкает новый процесс. Я в винде не силён, но можно же посмотреть в таск менеджере какие там реально pid и сравнить с тем, что есть в массиве

Comment: Это так. старт создает новый процесс. Но получить его айди я немогу